# Anon function and add_meta_box

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, metabox

I am building a WordPress management plugin (so far going really well) however I am having a slight issue below is what I am trying to acheive and the problem.

I am building a Meta manager and for the most part works.

I have created a custom post type called "meta_box" and created a dynamic field manager which works the problem I am having is after storing the meta box data in a post I am then running an anon function as follows:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', function (){

    $meta_box_query(
        'post_type'  =>  'meta_box',
        'post_status'  =>  'publish',
        'posts_per_page'  =>  -1
    );

    $meta_boxes = get_posts($meta_box_query);

    foreach ($meta_boxes as $meta_box) {

        $meta_title = $meta_box->post_title;
        $meta_id = preg_replace('-','_',$meta_box->post_name);
        $meta_screens = get_post_meta($meta_box->ID,'screens',true);
        add_meta_box(
            $meta_id,
            $meta_title,
            function(){
                // meta fields render code
            },
            $meta_screens,
            'advanced'
        );
    }

});
```

Now the above code loads the first meta box but doesn't load anymore. is there something I am missing? I was thinking would I need to add the index into the foreach loop or is it something else?

Any assistence with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: start with debuging what is in the array `$meta_boxes`.

Comment: I did that and the initial array is fine as soon as I put it through the foreach loop it returns 1 instead of 2 or 3 and so on.